# QGIS import variable existing .qgs file

Tags: qgis

I need to include in the file containing geographical coordinates of my region a new external variable that I would like to use to grade the colour of the different parts of the whole map. I know how to include a new column but the only way I found to copy in my new variable is to write data by hands. Is that the only way?

Comment: Can you be more precise about the format that your data has and how individual rows can be matched.

Comment: The rows can be matched using an ID number or the name of units (I am using coordinates of small cities). The data that I would like to upload is a .csv or .txt file. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a table join? http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html